# Best Approach To Load SVG as Inline in PHP - cURL or file_get_contents

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, svg

I'm writing this question after reading almost all similar questions on StackOverflow and other places, but still, couldn't get the answer I was looking for.

#### The Situation

I'm building a WordPress site where I have mostly used SVG illustrations when it comes to adding images. Now instead of using `<ing ... />` tag as I was using SVG I preferred to inline them all on the page. So, to achieve that I've wrote a small `cUURL` (why cURL will be explained below) function in my `functions.php` file as follows:

```php
/**
 * Uses cURL rather than to make a request to the specified URL.
 *
 * @param    string    $url       The URL to which we're making the request.
 * @return   string    $output    The result of the request.
 */
function url_get_contents( $url ) {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'curl_init' ) ) {
        die( 'The cURL library is not installed.' );
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    $output = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    return $output;
}
```

This works fine and returns my SVG file content and then I can simply do `echo url_get_contents('htttps://mysite.com/something/something/some.svg');`
I have no issue with making the code work.

#### The Problem & Why Not `file_get_contents()`

The main reason I initially didn't use `file_get_contents` is that I read in multiple StackOverflow questions that it is bad, slow and has security issues. No matter what questions I read all said the same thing `cURL` is way faster and better.

But my experience is not the same. When I made the site live, I started to notice some wired thing; i.e. a very high wait time especially on the initial requests. Also each time I am refreshing a page, a lot of `php-fpm` processes gets created on the server and consumes around 20-25% of CPU.

For example just to load the home page there were about 4-7 `php-fpm` instances getting created and eating resource. My host told me that this is not normal and there is something wrong. So, when I replaced my `cURL` based `url_get_contents()`, still multiple `php-fpm` processes were getting created but the page was loading a bit faster and the wait time was about 2-3 sec lower.

#### The Solution

I have no idea why this is happening so, if anyone can explain to me why this is happening and what is the best way to inline SVG files inside your pages, I would be really grateful. Should I use `cURL` or simply `file_get_contents()`? There is some page which loads as much as 8-10 SVG and then there are also pages which only loads 2-3 SVG as inline.

Looking forward to your valuable guidance.

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using a local path as opposed to a URL?  Using `file_get_contents()` on a local path will not need to open a connection to what it thinks may be a remote site.

Comment: Well, actually I have to see how can I do that. Currently what I am doing is getting the image id from the WordPress CMS, then using the `wp_get_attachment_url()` to get the URL of the file by passing the image ID.

But I think I can replace them with path like `/home/whatever/public/something.svg` that's what you mean right? 

Let me try that

Comment: @NigelRen I've updated the URLs with path and yes it has made things quite faster. But still, the wait time is about 1.8 sector 2.2 seconds. Any other tips to make it even faster? Also, there are still multiple PHP processes for a single page load getting created.